# Genius Season 1, a confusion in a quote

Tags: dialogue, genius

In Genius Season 1 Episode 1 at 9:00, Young Albert Einstein defies his teacher by solving the equation on board and states

> Natural log of constant multiplied by x equals natural log of one plus v squared. And since v equals y over x. That gives us the final function: x squared plus y squared minus c x cubed equals zero.

What is he talking about?

Comment: That bit doesn't appear to make sense in context. On the board they have the law of cosines, but he goes into solving some logarithm and uses an equation that wasn't present before.

Comment: There's some discussion of math that precedes that, see here:   http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=genius-2017&episode=s01e01    The main point seems to be stressing the Prussian style of rote memorization.  Rote vs Concept is a debate that continues today.   That's not the point of your question though.   I find the math rather confusing, they talk about trigonometry then the words differential equation then natural log.   I can't put it together but it's been a long time since I studied. Maybe this should go to a mathematics board for a better answer.